# Double Scroll with react-spring parallax & react-three-fiber `Canvas`

Tags: html, css, next.js, react-spring, react-three-fiber

I am trying to create a scrolling box with `parallax` but for some reasons it won't bound with `Canvas` element, even if I will include both under the same `<div>`.

In this screenshot, you can see div1 and div2 where each has its own scroll feature...
[image: screenshoot double scroll bar]

Tried in a separate divs
[image: sep div]

And even under the same div, still can't get rid of the double scroll. Any ideas?
[image: under same div]
[image: default funct]

Or `react-spring` **parallax** isn't compatible with `react-three-fiber` and that's why there is a library `react-three-flex`?

Here is the [codesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-moore-4epe4?file=/pages/index.js)

Comment: I recommend putting a code pen so people can look at the code.

Comment: @Josh tried to create a codebox but got an error...

[CODEBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-worker-hd1bf?file=/components/Duck.js)

Comment: You haven't added react-dom as a dependency, which is clearly written in the terminal

Comment: @Josh I thought that next.js has it bounded like a dependency... Thanks a lot, will try to make till the state where you can see the `sccrooling` effect - issue, will keep you updated

Comment: @Josh here you can see the scrolling effect (ISSUE) https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-moore-4epe4?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: R3F Drei has something called `<ScrollControls>`, which might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move the canvas into the Parallax container as a new `ParallaxLayer` like so – https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-dewdney-r0c0u?file=/components/Parallax.js

Comment: your code sandbox resolves the main scroll issue, but as we discussed parallax isn't designed to be used as I tended (too laggy) when combined. Thx